# CakePHP - Language not recognized

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

When I run the website built on CakePHP on a local server, it shows the correct, non-english version. However, if I run it on a server it shows the english version. I can manually set the language in core.php, but I want CakePHP to one of the two versions depending on the user's language.
How can I manage that?

With kind regads,

Battlestr1k3

Comment: Which version of Cake? Are you using cakephp's i18N?

Comment: Read the manual? It's described in detail on that page  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp including sample code.

Comment: Sorry burzum, but as I described, I want CakePHP to automatically set the language based on the users (browser-)language.
Yes, I am using CakePHP's i18n-System. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good article on this topic:

https://www.dyeager.org/blog/2008/10/getting-browser-default-language-php.html

Which basically says you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` [[details here]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to determine the language.  At that point, you'll have to follow the standard Cake procedures to change your app's language based on which language you detect.